Is this driver burnt?
I would like to ask if you can tell if a driver is burned out just by looking at the tracks and brown spots around the pins.
Let's take the case in the picture:
[![enter image description here][1]][1]
Obviously it should be turned on, tested for continuity between power supply and gnd etc..
..but my question is just referring to what you see with eyes.

brown spots around the pins ... where?

@jsotola Given my inexperience, I thought those brown patches in the upper right corner might be a problem

No, from the bottom side of a board you can't tell that (unless there's scorch marks or similar, which at least makes damage likely). The white residue is flux, and unproblematic.
I don't see any brown spots, so I can't comment on these. But again, I don't think the bottom side is very helpful here. Measure your board's components and traces.

So those brown spots on the right are not a sign of burning or anything? I also ask how do I measure "traces" ... do you mean continuity between different pins? Thanks!
